# How to easily create python package, keeping the folder structure and files?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a folder with structure like this (names are not real):

```
script0_1.py
script0_2.py
- folder1
  - folder1_1
    - script1_1_1.py
    - script1_1_2.py
  - folder1_2
    - script1_2_1.py
    - script1_2_2.py
- folder2
  - script2_1.py
- folder3
...
```

Important moment is that the structure can be changed, scripts added, etc. I want to create a package, to be able to run commands like this
`my_package.folder1.folder1_1.script1_1_1.some_func()`, easily. I know a bit that I can create `__init__.py` in each folder, then import all function one by one, but maybe there is an easier way?
Also, I'm interested, how to import all function in the folders or subfolders, but not by importing them in `__init__.py` one by one, for example if there is a function `my_package.folder1.folder1_1.script1_1_1.some_func()`, I can use simply `my_package.some_func()`

Comment: You don't import modules in the `__init__.py` file. By creating that file and leaving it empty, the Python interpreter will understand that there are python modules in that folder that can be imported. Regarding your last question, you can type `import my_package.folder1.folder1_1.script1_1_1 as my_package` and it'll do what you are asking

Comment: Anyway, you should look for a guide that explains how Python modules and packages work, and what's the purpose of `__init__.py`. There are plenty of posts and books covering this

Comment: This should help : <https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/>

Comment: @Jalo I don't know why, but having empty `__init__.py` in each folder doesn't work, if I write `my_package.folder1.folder1_1.script1_1_1.some_func()` nothing happens, but it certainly should

Comment: @Jalo or `AttributeError: module 'folder1' has no attribute 'folder1_1'` happens

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` in every single folder, not only the one where your scripts are located. In your example, you need `my_package/__init__.py`, `my_package/folder1/__init__.py`, and `my_package/folder1/folder1_1/__init__.py`. Do those exist?

Comment: @Arne yes, I did, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057462/how-to-use-existing-folder-structure-and-files-to-create-a-package